# Running PHP script as close to daily time as possible

Tags: php

I have a cron job that runs all scripts in my project. The cron runs every 10 mins. What I want to do is only run some specific code at a certain time every day.

The thing is, I can't change how often the cron runs, so it has to stay at 10 min intervals. What would be the best way to run some code as close to the given time only once a day?

I also have access to a variable that records the last updated time

```
$dailyTimeToRunCode = '10:00:00';
```

I'm not sure where to get started.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @tim, Cron jobs are running every 10min, however we don't know for sure if it's at 00, 10, 20, etc.

Comment: @tim but if the cron for that user runs at 22:58:00, then the next time it will get run is at 23:08:00 and the code will be completely skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't know for sure if crons will run at 00, 10, 20, etc. each hour, I came up with this solution.

**It will basically check if there's less than 10min left before 10:00:00 and wait exactly until that time:**

```
<?php

/* Set timezone and max execution time */
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

/* First, check if we are 10min or less before the desired launch time */
$dailyTimeToRunCode = '10:00:00';
$time_left = strtotime(date('Y-m-d '.$dailyTimeToRunCode)) - time();
if ($time_left > 0 && $time_left < 10 * 60)
{
    /* Wait to until the desired exact time */
    sleep($time_left);

    /* Do something */
}
```

Comment: Now thats an interesting solution ... That should work perfectly. Thank you Bruno!

Comment: To do this. Do I have to load or open this page and wait until it trigger something at the time expected?